# React Navigation 6.x Initial Route Not Working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-navigation-v6, react-native-deep-linking

I'm using React Navigation 6.x's linking with Expo so that when a user clicks on a notification they are directed to the appropriate part of my application to interact with the new information. When my app is backgrounded (running in the background) and a user clicks on a notification they are redirected to the screen they need to be at, which works perfectly fine. However, when the app is killed and the user clicks on a notification, they are taken directly to the screen for which the url is provided and they cannot press back to navigate elsewhere in my application. I tried to resolve this by using the `initialRouteName` prop like is shown in the docs (link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#rendering-an-initial-route), but I cannot get it to work. For further clarification, when I mentioned above that I am able to get linking working it is in relation to the direct `SettingsScreen`, `AddFriendScreen`, and `MessagingScreen` links. What I cannot get working is the specific block of code inside the liking object that starts with `HomeScreen`. What I believe may be causing the issue is that I am trying to set my `initialRoute` as a screen within `HomeScreen`'s `Tabs.Navigator` and then trying to route to a screen within my `Stack.Navigator`. However, the docs show that this is possible (link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#rendering-an-initial-route).

My code:

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config: {
        screens: {
            HomeScreen: {
                initialRouteName: "Chats",
                screens: {
                    AddFriendScreen: "addFriend",
                    CreateChatScreen: "createChatScreen",
                    Friends: "friends",
                    MessagingScreen: 'messagingScreen/:chatRoomId'
                }
            },
            SettingsScreen: "SettingsScreen",
            AddFriendScreen: "AddFriendScreen",
            MessagingScreen: 'MessagingScreen/:chatRoomId'
        },
    }
};

<NavigationContainer linking={linking} theme={MyTheme} >
    <Stack.Navigator>
        {!authState.value ? 
            <>
                <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="SignUpScreen" component={SignUpScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPasswordScreen" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
            </>
        :
            <>
                <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="MessagingScreen" component={MessagingScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="CreateChatScreen" component={CreateChatScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="AddFriendScreen" component={AddFriendScreen} />
            </>
        }
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <Tabs.Navigator>
            <Tabs.Screen name="Chats" component={ChatScreen} />
            <Tabs.Screen name="Friends" component={FriendsScreen} />
            <Tabs.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        </Tabs.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would put any screen that I would like to access in multiple navigators at the root level so that they can both reach it.

For my own project, I have a root stack with a dedicated auth stack and an app/home stack (which is a tab nav like your `HomeScreen`). And outside that I have all my modal and root screens that I'd like other navigators to access (Because I really have two Home tab navigators the user can switch between.)

Idk if putting all of your screens listed after `HomeScreen` outside of that object will help your situation, but you can try that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).